# Merging Multiple Wordpress Websites

Tags: php, multisite

I have multiple wordpress sites using subdomains, I want to merge all of them, If I create Multisite network on my main domain, is it Possible to merge existing wordpress sites into it ?

Or is there any other way by which I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting it up and importing? to my knowledge it treats each site on multisite as its own so if you set up a new site within the multisite environment you should be able to import the single site, then repeat the process for each one

Comment: Can you suggest any good plugin for import and export process, also can you guide me with procedure ?

Comment: There is plenty of import tutorials out there.... but try this... https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-site-into-multisite/

Comment: Thanks, my website which I want to export and import to the network contains woocommerce and various plugin, so if i disable those before importing, I’ll lose all the setting products etc

Comment: It's a paid plugin, but has a good reputation and lots of support: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/multisite-tools-addon/

Comment: This may be helpful: https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/how-to/combine-wordpress-multisite